# Scraping with Curl : error setting Cookies

Tags: curl

I try to **scrape** some date from a website with curl. Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=Les+bourgeois');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
$result7 = htmlspecialchars_decode(curl_exec ($ch));
curl_close($ch);

$html7 = new simple_html_dom();
$html7->load($result7);
```

But I have the following Warning error:

> Warning: file_get_contents( <!DOCTYPE html> <html xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" lang="en" > <head> <script type="text/javascript"> var JiffyParams = { jsStart: (new Date()).getTime()}; </script> <meta name="robots" content="noarchive,noindex,nofollow,NOODP" /> <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true"/> <title>JSTOR: An Error Occurred Setting Your User Cookie</title> <meta charset="UTF-8"/> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/templates/jsp/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jawrcss/N815843185/bundles/jstor.css" /> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,5 in C:\wamp\www\scrape_cairn\simple_html_dom.php on line 76

I don't understand what is my mistake, I'm a beginner with Curl... Maybe I have to set some cookies from Jstor but I don't know how to do. Thank you for your Help.

EDIT :

I just added this and the error changed:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=Les+bourgeois');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, random_user_agent());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    $result7 = htmlspecialchars_decode(curl_exec ($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
```

the error:

Warning: file_get_contents(<!DOCTYPE html><!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en" ><![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en" ><!--<![endif]--><head><script type="text/javascript">(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={xpid:"VwACUF9VGwsGXVRbAwA="};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n){if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n][0].call(o.exports,function(e){var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o?o:e)},o,o.exports)}return e[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({QJf3ax:[function(t,e){function n(t){function e(e,n,a){t&&t(e,n,a),a||(a={});for(var c=s(e),f=c.length,u=i(a,o,r),d=0;f>d;d++)c[d].apply(u,n);return u}function a(t,e){f[t]=s(t).concat(e)}function s(t){return f[t]||[]}function c(){return n(e)}var f={};return{on:a,emit:e,create:c,listeners:s,_events: in C:\wamp\www\scrape_cairn\simple_html_dom.php on line 76

I add the piece of code from simple_html_dom about the line 76:

```
    function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
    //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure `file_get_html()` is the good way to do that ? This function calls [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php), which opens an URI, and you pass a string (containing your HTML data).

I think [str_get_html()](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#api) from PHP Simple HTML DOM would be the good way.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are a browser thing.

curl is a system thing (bash or linux or something).

php wraps up curl (and sometimes actually compiles libraries within). It is more or less a system call (no browser involved)

Hence, you'll need to set cookies with curl:

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html

But you are right -

Comment: Thank you, how can I get the cookies from Jstor to set with Curl? Can I use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and after CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE ?

Comment: Why do you need this: "CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION" ? maybe a cookie thing - more to follow.  The code you have worked for me - fine.  However, I did not use new_simple_html_dom().  And I set the user_agent

Comment: I updated my question. Terary: I thank it was the problem initialy but when I remove the followlocation it doesn't change anything..

Comment: Yeah - sorry I was a little off. Chase bugs can be a tricky business.  I dont think your issue is curl - I ran the code you had minus simple_html_..., and it runs, the last line of your error message is '...\simple_html_dom.php on line 76'  -- try running it with out html_dom, an refocus your bug hunt.  I would help more but I gots to be at the J.O.B.   .. good luck.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep going searching. Anyway I add the piece of code from simple_hteml_dom in the question